# Behavior of ArcTan when two zeros are given as arguments

Tags: trigonometry

I've noticed that the numeric approximation of `ArcTan` is a bit different from the symbolic one.

If I write

```
ArcTan[0,0]
```

I obtain

```
ArcTan::indet: "Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0,0] encountered.
```

While if I write

```
ArcTan[0.0, 0]
```

I obtain

```
0
```

Instead I expect to obtain also in this case an indeterminate result. Is there some specific reason for this behavior?

=== EDIT ===

[J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) has noticed also this:

```
ArcTan[0, 0.0]
```

gives

```
Pi/2
```

=== EDIT 2 ===

[celtschk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/129/celtschk) also noticed that

```
ArcTan[0.0, 0.0]
```

gives

```
ArcTan::indet: "Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0.,0.] encountered.
```

but it *does* generate an output:

```
Interval[{-Pi, Pi}]
```

#### Edit 2015-11-29

I ran into this problem while working with some code in V10.3. I found this question (obviously), but since the V10.3 behavior is different, I thought I should edit the and report that behavior. -- m_goldberg

[image: v10.3]

Comment: Additional quirk: compare `ArcTan[0., 0]` and `ArcTan[0, 0.]`. Hmm...

Comment: Interesting, I didn't notice it...

Comment: Now we know for sure that rule30 is extensively used

Comment: @belisarius: Why is that so? I fail to see the immediate link, care to explain?

Comment: `ArcTan[0.0,0.0]` again gives `ArcTan::indet`.

Comment: @István belisarius has an uncommon sense of humor :-)

Comment: I can pretend that I got the subtle hint and smile appreciatively on the Mma insider joke - but I do not have the slightest idea what is goi.... ooh, I see. Uncommon, indeed :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `ArcTan[0,0]`, you tell Mathematica that the parameters `x` and `y` in `ArcTan[x,y]` are the exact integer 0. As we know, `0/0` cannot be unambiguously defined, and `Indeterminate` is returned. So `ArcTan[0,0]` returns the result of `Interval[{-Pi,Pi}]`, for the codomain of `ArcTan[0,0]` is just between -Pi and Pi.

On the other hand, if you write `ArcTan[0.0,0]`, `y` is the exact integer 0, but `x` is approximate real numbers which approaches 0 but not the exact interger 0. Therefore, `(exact 0)/(approximate 0) = exact 0`, resulting in `ArctTan[0.,0] == 0`.( Similar for `ArcTan[0,0.] == Pi/2`)

Now, consider why `ArcTan[0.,0.]` returns `Interval[{-Pi,Pi}]`, similar to `ArcTan[0,0]`. For this question, we must first keep it in mind that every approximate real numbers in Mathematica has its finite precision and accuracy. The default precision in Mathematica can be obtained by `$MachinePrecision`, which is 15.9546.

So, in the default setting, the paremeters `x` and `y` in `ArcTan[0.,0.]` have the same precision. Let me draw an analogy: when x and y have the the same precision 10,they can see each other the same effective number of digits, that is, the first 10 numbers of x and y are all 0. As for the 11th number and those after that, Mathematica did not take them into account when calculating, since those numbers are out of the precision and ambiguous. As a result, `ArcTan[0.,0.]` involves the situation `0/0`, returning `Indeterminate`.

Now, let us make a little change-just increase one of parameters (x or y) to the precision 16, such as `ArcTan[N[0,16],0.]`, which returns `Pi/2`. This is because x=N[0,16] has greater precision than y=0. (which is just 15.9546). So, y with the precision of 15.9546 can only see x the first 15.9546 numbers and think x is 0, while x with precision 16 can see what the y's 16th number is and think y is not 0. Hence, `(Not 0)/0` causes `Infinity`. (Similar to `ArcTan[0.,N[0,16]]` returning 0)

The above analogy may be inexact, but in short, the phenomenon in question is related to the precision of real numbers in Mathematica.

If you expect to obtain in the case of `ArcTan[0.,0]` an indeterminate result, you can use `Chop` function. `ArcTan[Chop[0.],0]` returns `Indeterminate`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's not exactly "greater precision"; ponder on the outputs of `$MachinePrecision == MachinePrecision`, `ArcTan[N[0, $MachinePrecision], N[0, MachinePrecision]]` and `ArcTan[N[0, MachinePrecision], N[0, $MachinePrecision]]`...

Comment: @J.M. I think your example is because of the…er…strange property of `$MachinePrecision`, according to the document,  _`$MachinePrecision` is numerically `Equal` to `MachinePrecision`_, but _`$MachinePrecision` uses arbitrary precision computations with machine precision resolution_. In fact `NumberForm@N[0, $MachinePrecision]` is `0`, while `NumberForm@N[0, MachinePrecision]` is `0.`…

Comment: But the behaviour of `ArcTan[0.0, 0.0]` is still unresolved, also, why doesn't `ArcTan[0, -0.]` return `-Pi/2`?

Comment: @xzczd, ack, I forgot that `N[0, stuff]` still returns an exact zero if `stuff =!= MachinePrecision`...

Comment: Well, coming back to this answer after playing with _Mathematica_ for 3 more years, I noticed that I didn't fully understand @J.M. 's comment at that time. Now I'm quite sure this answer is not perfect and has even made several mistakes (e.g. mixing up `MachinePrecision` and `$MachinePrecision`, not noticing `N[0, 16]` still returns an exact zero rather than an approximate zero with precision `16`). Oh, now I can answer the "why doesn't `ArcTan[0, -0.]` return `-Pi/2`" question myself, it's because `-0.` evaluates to `0.`, which I think is a not-hard-to-accept default behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I think you get this result because for Mathematica handles 0.0 here as a number which approaches 0.

Define e.g.

```
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[y/x]
```

As for `ArcTan[0,0]` you get for `f[0,0]` a not meaningful result (lastly because a point at (0,0) can enclose with the abscissa all angles from [-π,π], therefore also the output `Interval[{-π,π}]`).

But if you use

```
 Limit[f[x, 0], x -> 0]
```

You get as for `ArcTan[0.,0]`  as result 0.
The same works if you use the limit for y:

`ArcTan[0,0.]` and `Limit[Limit[f[x,y],x -> 0],y -> 0]`give as result π/2.

So, by writing ArcTan[0,0.] you are telling Mathematica that you are approaching the (0,0) on the  y-axis and this gives then the same result as e.g. ArcTan[0,10] (similar for ArcTan[0.,0]).

If you use ArcTan[0.,0.] you are approaching (0,0) on both axes to the same time. This is geometrically not possible (the point can only be on both axes to the same time in the origin of the coordinate system; thats why I used two limits above), therefore you get here again as result `Interval[{-π,π}]`.

Comment: @Nasser M. Abbasi: I corrected the code in my answer so that you have it in the correct form after copying it from here.

Comment: Then why doesn't `ArcTan[0.,0.]` return `Interval[{-π/2,π/2}]`?

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps this is mathematicas standard output when the expression is indeterminate?

Answer (score 5):

I used `Arg[x + i y]` to compute `ArcTan[y/x]`, and it gives 0 for all the variations of `x = 0` and `y = 0` mentioned in the description.

Comment: It's true it doesn't answer the question, but it does address the issue of a work around for someone wanting a single solution to zero/near zero values of ArcTan.