# User defined ArcTan function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, trigonometry

I am trying to integrate an equation that requires an angle term calculated using `ArcTan[x,y]`. A number of issues have been mentioned about `ArcTan` in some of the older questions ([Link here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/behavior-of-arctan-when-two-zeros-are-given-as-arguments)) and I wanted the `ArcTan` function to give out `0` as an output when I give `ArcTan[0,0]` as an input.

I have defined my ArcTan function as:

```
myArcTan[x_,y_] := Which[x > 0 || y > 0 || x < 0 || y < 0 , ArcTan[x, y], 
x == 0 && y == 0, 0];
```

**Question1:** Is `myArcTan` correctly defined for what I am trying to do?.

When I use `myArcTan` as one of the terms in the indefinite integral given below, I get a different answer than when using `ArcTan`. Definite integral, however, gives the same result for both the cases:

```
Integral1 = Integrate[myArcTan[x, y], y, x]
Integral1 /. {x -> 1, y -> 0}
Out[2]= 1/4

Integral2 = Integrate[ArcTan[x, y], y, x] 
Integral2 /. {x -> 1, y -> 0}
Out[4]= 0

Integrate[myArcTan[x, y], {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
Out[5]= 0

Integrate[ArcTan[x, y], {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
Out[6]= 0
```

**Question 2:** One of the answers given in the older question ([Link here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/behavior-of-arctan-when-two-zeros-are-given-as-arguments)) uses `Arg[x + i y]` but an indefinite integral using `Arg` does not evaluate. Only a numerical approximation using `NIntegrate` works on it. Why is this so?, can one do an indefinite integral using `Arg`?.

Comment: An indefinite integral is not a function. It’s an equivalence class of functions up to constant difference (the $+C$ from calculus). Mathematica gives one representative of that equivalence class. Perhaps that’s what you’re seeing. From the Help in Mathematica 11: “Different forms of the same integrand can give integrals that differ by constants of integration.”

Comment: Right, I totally forgot about it. But, I'm still not sure about the problem of `ArcTan[0,0]` being undefined and my implementation of it (`myArcTan`).

Comment: Have you tried out some of the alternate expressions listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)?

Comment: @J.M. As per Wikipedia `myArcTan` looks correct to me other than the `ArcTan[0,0]` value which is undefined in Wikipedia and `0` by my definition.

Comment: I see. I'll only note that it's more natural to use `Piecewise[]`: `Piecewise[{{ArcTan[x, y], x != 0 || y != 0}}, 0]`